# Angular UI Google Maps center marker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, angular-ui

I'm using Angular(UI)-Google-Maps (2.1.5) and AngularJS (1.3.13)

I want a marker that is always in the center of the map. The problem is that the marker only updates its position when I stop dragging.

I use the drag event like this:

```
drag: function(maps) {     
    $scope.map.marker.center.coords = $scope.map.center;
}
```

I also count the amount, how often the drag event triggers, which is much higher than the updates of the marker (or map). Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/M39CFc

I also tried `center_changed` and `bounds_changed` with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put the marker in the center of the map make use of the following                                                                                                                                                                                                             tag:

```
<ui-gmap-marker coords="map.center" idkey="1" ng-cloak>
```

Although this technique is discouraged as it will also move the marker when the map is dragged. To get a workaround with this situation use:

```
marker.coords = Object.create(coords)
```

Comment: Nice it's working, but on mobile the problem still exitsts.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to add the property draggable = true to the markers:

```
 <ui-gmap-markers coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" options="{ draggable: true }">
```

Don't know why this solve the issue in IE, [check this](http://blog.amielmartin.com/post/24427639015/google-maps-api-with-custom-markers-in-internet)